# std::filesystem не отображает все файлы в некоторых директориях

Tags: c++, поиск, файловая-система, итераторы, std

Господа, у меня код не отображает все файлы, находящиеся в определенных папках (не во всех, обычно, где много файлов). Читал несколько статей с похожей проблемой и я так понял дело в скрытых файлах windows, об которые "спотыкается" iterator, хотя ошибки явной компилятор не выдает. Пробовал несколько вариантов:

1. Пробовал решить эту проблему одной из перегрузок рекурсивного итератора директории -  "directory_options::skip_permission_denied", но результат тот же.
2. Также думал, что дело в кодировках, поэтому добавил всевозможные сетлокали и SetConsoleCP. Тоже дело не в этом
3. Пробовал название каждого файла пушить в вектор - ничего.

код:

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

char folderpath[100];
cout << "Path: >> ";
cin.getline(folderpath, 100000);

wstring name;
wstring extension;

for (const auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(folderpath, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied))
    {
        if (!p.is_regular_file())
        {
            continue;
        }

        name = p.path().filename();
        extention = name.substr(name.find_last_of('.'));

        wcout << i++ << " " << name << " " << extention << p.file_size() << endl;
    }
```

Сразу оговорюсь, я понимаю, что дело не в лыжах - сам дурак, подскажите только куда воевать.

Comment: В каких точно папках? Если память не изменяет, всякие "мои документы", "картинки" и т.п. - это суммы нескольких отдельных папок - пользовательской и общей системной.

Comment: Ну я пробую ввести путь, в котором содержатся стандартные "загрузки". Ну к примеру папку со скачанными файлами из telegram: \Downloads\Telegram Desktop

Comment: Это полный путь? И какие файлы не отображает? Много ли их?

Comment: Не выводит в консоль файлы, которые находятся по этой директории (их там штук 200). Вернее не все файлы, первые 20 выводит, а после завершается с кодом 0. Полный путь вот: C:\Users\Downloads\Telegram Desktop

Comment: А нерекурсивным итератором попробуйте. Еще можно попробовать старой сишной функцией `opendir`.

Comment: Пробовал нерекурсивным, все тоже самое. Сишную функцию я так и не понял как использовать, она возвращает указатель на папку, а нам это к данному случаю неприменимо, мне кажется

Comment: Почитайте мануал к той функции. Она как раз нужна чтобы получать список файлов в папке.

Comment: Удивительно, но, если выводить "extention", то все файлы без проблем выводятся в консоль. Вернее их расширения, а не названия. Я попробовал добавлять их в вектор

Comment: Может у вас русские буквы не выводятся? Или ещё какие-то странные символы?

Comment: В том то все и дело. Я тестировал код на вывод различных символов, специально даже переименовывал файлы в отдельной папке и он их выводил. Чтобы точно исключить все вопросы с кодировкой я добавил SetLocale и SetConsoleCP - эту штуку часто советуют включать, чтобы не было проблем с выводом. Но дело не в этом

Comment: Вы бы всё-таки привели *полный путь* и *название* проблемного файла. Так легче будет вам помочь.

Comment: Да нет проблемных файлов. Программа должна работать вроде как парсер названий файлов, лежащих в директории по пути, указанному пользователем. Программа работает нормально с папками, в которых немного файлов, но где много, не выводит в консоль все файлы и завершает нулем, то есть ошибок нет. Может быть дело в windows, может быть в filesystem или я чего то не дописал. В этом весь вопрос